# Remove blur background after popup dismiss

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers: `MainViewController` and `PopupViewController`. From main controller I have an imageview with a long press gesture recognizer, on long tap i'm calling my popup view controller and use blur on my main controller:

```
var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

@IBAction func addGamePopup(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began){

        self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.blurEffectView.alpha = 1;
        });

        let popupView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddGamePopup")
        self.present(popupView, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark))
    self.blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Then I'm doing my thin in popup controller and call

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But now I need to remove my `blurEffectView` from main view. Something like this, but where should I do this? I can't access this view from my popup controller and i don't know how to trigger some event when popup is dismissed

```
blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same situation as yours, and i did it using protocols to pass data back to the first ViewController(in your case, MainViewController) telling it to hide the blur.

Here's how i did it:

This is the first ViewController(MainViewController in your case). You create and implement the protocol and conform its methods.

```
import UIKit

//here you can name your protocol and the function whatever you want and set the values you want to pass back, in our case a boolean
protocol esconderBlurProtocol {
    func isEsconder(value: Bool)
}

//you have to extend the controller to your protocol and conform its methods, in this case the function isEsconder, and inside it you do whatever you want.
//In our case hide the blur if the value we are receiving is true
class PalestrantesVC: UIViewController,esconderBlurProtocol {

    func isEsconder(value: Bool) {
        if(value){
            blur.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Now for your second ViewController, its pretty easy. Just create a variable of your protocol type(in my case, esconderBlurProtocol).

```
class DetalhePalestranteVC: UIViewController {

     var delegate: esconderBlurProtocol?
```

And use it calling its function when you desire(in our case, when we're closing this ViewController), sending the value True back to our previous ViewController:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     delegate?.isEsconder(value: true)
}
```

And to finish you have to set the instance of your protocol to your first ViewController when you're opening your second ViewController, like this:

```
let viewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetalhePalestranteVC")) as! DetalhePalestranteVC
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
viewController.delegate = self
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thats it. Sorry if its messy as english is not my main language.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what i needed

Comment: Glad i could help! Can you please mark the answer as right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call `blurEffectView?.removeFromSuperview` inside `viewWillDisappear()` or `viewDidDisappear` from the **viewController** of the **popup**